# Does Android supports recording through OpenMAX AL APIs?

Tags: android, android-ndk, openmax

I have been trying to record audio/video on Android device and play it back using Open MAX AL APIs.

So far, audio playback part works smoothly. I referred [native-media](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/native-media) example to play mp4 file from the SD card using *Media Player* object. Before trying video playback, I started exploring audio recording.

While trying recording, I realized that `Engine::CreateMediaRecorder` returns `SL_RESULT_FEATURE_UNSUPPORTED`.

1. Does that mean, Android does not support recording through OpenMAXAL APIs?
2. [This](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/ndk/docs/openmaxal/) link partially talks about some of the features except *Media Recorder*. Where are the Android supported features of OpenMAXAL documented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is not supported. Please refer [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/ky6cxG8u9u0) reply from Glenn Kasten.